# Script SQL com erro, podem me ajudar?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, script, syntax-error

estou com um projeto a ser feito, o projeto em si consiste em criar um script sql com base em modelo entidade e relacionamento, a apostila em si não está muito bem formulada e com base no que eu entendi cheguei no seguinte Script

"Nossa disciplina gira em torno do desenvolvimento e entrega de um projeto. Nesse projeto pedimos para que em base a um modelo, crie scripts SQL que atendam a expectativa da proposta. Ou seja, escrever o script de criação das três tabelas: Aluno, Matricula e Classe."

RESPOSTA:

```
-- Table `mydb`.`Aluno`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Aluno` ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Aluno` (
  `Nr_Rgm` DECIMAL(8) NOT NULL,
  `Nm_Nome` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `Nm_Pai` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `Nm_Mae` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `Dt_Nascimento` DATE NULL,
  `Id_Sexo` CHAR(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Nr_Rgm`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;




-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Classe`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Classe` ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Classe` (
  `Cd_Classe` DECIMAL(8) NOT NULL,
  `Nr_AnoLetivo` DECIMAL(4) NULL,
  `Nr_Serie` DECIMAL(2) NULL,
  `Sg_Turma` VARCHAR(2) NULL,
  `Cd_Escola` DECIMAL(6) NULL,
  `Cd_Grau` DECIMAL(2) NULL,
  `Cd_Periodo` DECIMAL(2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Cd_Classe`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;




-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Matricula`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Matricula` ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Matricula` (
  `Nr_Rgm` DECIMAL(8) NOT NULL,
  `Cd_Classe` DECIMAL(8) NOT NULL,
  `Dt_Matricula` DATE NULL,
  `Aluno_Nr_Rgm` DECIMAL(8) NOT NULL,
  `Classe_Cd_Classe` DECIMAL(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Nr_Rgm`, `Cd_Classe`, `Aluno_Nr_Rgm`, `Classe_Cd_Classe`),
  INDEX `fk_Matricula_Aluno1_idx` (`Aluno_Nr_Rgm` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Matricula_Classe1_idx` (`Classe_Cd_Classe` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Matricula_Aluno1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Aluno_Nr_Rgm`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Aluno` (`Nr_Rgm`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Matricula_Classe1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Classe_Cd_Classe`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Classe` (`Cd_Classe`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

estou usando o SQLFIDDLE para testar  o script e o esmo está apresentando erro, "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" fora esse erro creio q tenha bem mais pois como eu disse q apostila não explica muito bem como fazer o script e esse script foi feito com base no que eu entendi
alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você realmente quer usar `oracle`?

Claramente você está cometendo um engano, por que você está usando comandos MySQL, mas o [erro apresentado é do oracle (ORA-00933)](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00933_sql_command_ended.htm).

Se você apenas remover o **`mydb`.** do script e executar no `MySQL 5.6` do fiddle, tudo funcionará perfeitamente.

[Veja como ficou no SQLfiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/163cef)

Comment: obrigado por me ajudar

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, marque como aceita @WíílSantos. :)